# Android show soft keyboard when fragment onResume

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments, android, android-input-method

I was trying to show keyboard when a screen with EditText is in foreground.. I found two solutions, surprisingly, both work on certain cases and NOT the other..

I have two fragments, the first fragment only shows keyboard when I call showSoftKeyboard1 and the second fragment only works if I call showSoftKeyboard2. both are called inside onResume();

```
public static void showSoftKeyboard1(Context activity, View view) {
    if (view == null) return;
    view.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
}

public static void showSoftKeyboard2(Activity activity, View view) {
    if (view == null) return;
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I wonder what is the difference between these two methods?!

Comment: simply use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" for your Activity in the manifest.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question..

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Not sure why it's necessary though. I just wanted the keyboard to show whenever my fragment was visible. But I was having the issue where if I sent the app to the background and brought it to the foreground, it wouldn't show the keyboard again. I tried both methods you listed individually until I found your solution. Thank you for that.